# ATmega - magnitude comparator for hardware PWM

Tags: pwm, atmega

Does someone has an information how hardware PWMs of ATmega, etc.. compare registers with timer/counter value? Is there inside a true 8bit magnitude comparator for every channell or is there some simplified solution? Or am I totally out?

Comment: What do you mean "magnitude comperator"? Also, have you read any Atmega datasheets? They might solve your problem there.  I would suggest datasheet of atmega328p, which is maybe the most famous atmega (due to the arduino).

Comment: The datasheets have pretty extensive documentation on the various PWM modes

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios A digital comparator with greater than output Q = (A>B)

Comment: @Mat Thx, I read the datasheet but I am more curious about what is inside of these hw pwm blocks to inspirate myself to make my own.

Comment: As far as I know it is an identity comparator. The output compare interrupt will only be triggered, if the CNT register value is equal to the COMP register value.

Comment: @jusaca Thanks, I was thinking about equality only also, it is lot of easier to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The [ATmega datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf) says on p. 128:

> **16.7  Output Compare Units**
> The 16-bit comparator continuously compares TCNT1 with the Output Compare Register (OCR1x).
> **If TCNT equals OCR1x the comparator signals a match.**

It says the same about the ouput compare unit for the 8 Bit TCNT0.

So I would strongly assume that for simplicity reasons only an identity comparator is used. It only checks if all bits are equal. A magnitude comparator would be overkill.